# URL query clearing php code problem

Tags: php

This is the code that im using for clear any queries in my url..

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  $pageURL = substr( $pageURL, 0, strrpos( $pageURL, "?")); 
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

this clears

> www.mydomian.com/myurl.html?***********

result is

> www.mydomian.com/myurl.html

Its done....but the thing it when its come with normal URL

> www.mydomian.com/myurl.html

The result is EMPLTY,NO RESULT ! 
BUT i want as it is.. 
no change..

> www.mydomian.com/myurl.html

i want the result normall url as it is...
Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[strrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) returns `FALSE` if the search string wasn't found.

```
$pageURL = strrpos( $pageURL, "?") !== FALSE ?
   substr( $pageURL, 0, strrpos( $pageURL, "?")) : $pageURL;
```

or

```
if (FALSE != ($pos = strrpos( $pageURL, "?")))
   $pageURL = substr( $pageURL, 0, $pos);
```